# Relative div overlapping Fixed Divs

Tags: html, css

I'm developing a mobile app, and I'm having an issue with relative divs going above the top and bottom header that are fixed with a z-index. I did some research and tried to put a z-index in the relative div, but it did not fix anything.

Here's the Relative Div:

```
    <div class="pure-u-1-3">
        <div class="TopMobBlock">
            <div class="TopMobName">Open Slot</div>
            <center>
                <div class="TopMobImage">
                    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Open&w=100&h=100" height="100%" width="100%" />
                </div>
            </center>   
            <center><input type="submit" class="TopMobBlank" value="Claim Bonus" /></center>
            <center><input type="submit" class="TopMobBlank" value="Send Energy" /></center>
            <div class="TopMobOpenBlock">
                <div class="TopMobOpenText">Open Slot</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's an edited version to just show the issue: 
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vzpatbhq/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your relative elements are using z-indexes, your fixed position elements will need to have a greater index to appear on top.

In your example JSFiddle, if I add `z-index: 3;` or greater to `.StatsBar` and `.TabsBar` it seems to fix it.

Comment: But Originally I didn't have the z-index inside of the relative div, I saw that it could fix it, but it didn't so what could be the reason for that fixing the issue?

Comment: I see what the issue is, I removed the z-index accidently on the `.StatsBar` and the `.TabsBar` when the relative div was acting up. Thank you very much for pointing that out to me. Lol

Answer (score 0):

From your example I can see that StatsBar and TabsBar are fixed but without a z-index.
If you always want them to appear above everything else try adding a z-index value to them. For example 20.
Then add .ActivePage { z-index: 10; position:relative; }.
This will keep your header and footer always at the top of your ActivePage div.

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative;` and `z-index: -1;` to `.pure-u-1-3`:

```
.pure-u-1-3 {
    width: 32%;
    width: 31.9690%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3Ljtywov/1/